# VScode isn't creating a file with python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using this code to create a file with "AAA" written in it. It's working in the regular python IDLE but isn't working in VScode.

```
with open("another.txt","w") as myfile:
    myfile.write("AAA")
```

Comment: what is the current working directory when running in VSC

Answer (score 0):

If no error is reported, then the file is successfully created somewhere. As you are using a relative path the file is probably saved to current working directory.

You can find it either via the path displayed in the terminal you are using, or in your Python code:

```py
from pathlib import Path
print(Path.cwd())
```